# Scale on inclined plane

Tags: electrical-engineering

Suppose a common scale using 4 load cells is placed on an inclined surface and gives a 1kg reading for a given load. Will the 'true' weight of the load be (precisely) `1kg / cos(theta)` where theta is the angle of the plane? This should be true in physics, but is it the case in practice for common bathroom scales? Being on an inclined plane, different forces will be applied to the load cells. Should that matter?

Comment: Do the instructions say to keep the scale level? If so, behaviour at an angle cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: @SolarMike But what's the explanation to the discrepancy between physics theory and load cells/electronics/practice?

Comment: run a test ....

Comment: How cheap the cells are would be an obvious first guess.

Comment: I might be inclined to have concern about excess shear forces. ;)

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as a "common scale" or "common bathroom scales". There is no reason to think that they are all made the same way. Every scale could respond differently.

Comment: This should not have been migrated.  It is off-topic *everywhere* because it concerns the behavior of a particular but utterly unspecified *product*, rather than the actual physics of the situation.  SE policy is that problematic questions must be closed at the source site, *not* migrated.  The most practical answer is to try it, but you can't rely on what it does in an out-of-designed situation today staying true over other examples or even the same one over time.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Usually the electric scales have one load cell with a mechanism to balance the offset loading that happens due to not standing in optimal point on the scale.

One would assume the same applies to an scale with a four cell scale.

If that is the case and the scale does not have circuitry to take into account small unevenness of the support, then the scale will read $  m_{scale}= m_{real}\cdot cos\alpha .$

Comment: That's not a remotely reliable conclusion.  It might actually be true in some cases.  It might misleadingly seem true in others until off-axis loading wrecks its toll.  It might fortunately seem completely off right from the start in other still.  If you want to measure only the vertical component, you need a mechanical stage which properly loads the cell with only that component.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, basic rule of vectors says so. Imagine if the scale is gradually tilting to 45 degrees, along with a growing horizontal component the force imparted to the scale will be reduced to sqrt(2)times m. and the more tilt the less force is received by the scale.

Comment: **In a word, "No".**  The problem is that you cannot cleanly apply simple physics to predict the behavior of an actual device in which far more factors are probably involved.  As previously explained, if you have a mechanical stage with is able to isolate the vertical component *only* and apply that to the load cell, then this would be correct.  But without such a setup, the behavior of a load cell under *side loading* is something that cannot be guessed without information that is utterly missing from the question.  **Abuse a sensor, get meaningless results!**.

Comment: Sounds like unsubstantiated, incorrect statement. Shoe reference.

Comment: The "basic rule of vectors" (whatever that is) is irrelevant.  If you use the scale in a way that it was not designed for, the load might not even be reaching the sensors. It might be going along a different load path. This is a question about engineering, not something you find in a textbook about high school level mechanics.

Comment: @alephzero, nothing is wrong with high school math, albeit many of us did not learn it. High school math, sciences are the absolute minimum everybody should know. As for the engineering of a scale, I venture to say most likely the mechanism that conveys the forces of the plate to the load cell/s is very "basic".